# Is there significant overhead in repetitively calling C++ within v8 JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c++, game-engine, v8, embedded-v8

I wish to develop a JavaScript game engine that uses C++ as a back-end for rendering/updates/collision etc. Pretty much all the heavy lifting stuff.

There would then be C++ classes/functions that are exposed through modifying the `isolate` variable (or maybe just a native nodejs module). Some of these classes, like the `Sprite` class, could have its `update` function overridden by a JS subclass in order to allow users to customize the behavior.

Finally, the game engine would run in a loop within the JavaScript, but every frame would make a call to the C++ context to update/render and all the stuff PLUS there would be tons of calls to check input, collision, etc. Not to mention all the callbacks each subclass would make to the parent classes written in C++.

My concern is that I have read there is significant overhead (more than normal) when calling C++ from the JS context (be it ffi or native modules). Usually it's worth it for the performance, but considering how many calls would be made back and forth between the two languages each frame, perhaps this wouldn't be the best idea? Instead, maybe something like Python would be more appropriate due to its zero overhead (though Python in general is much slower), or a different JS interpreter all together?

Comment: All function calls, to whatever language, have an overhead.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Well, yeah, obviously, but certain scenarios can cause greater overhead than others, and I'm asking about this very specific case. A call from within C++ to a C++ or JS to a JS function is drastically different from JS to C++ within v8. I don't see why it's such a ridiculous question to ask in regards to it?

Comment: Python in general is slow. Perhaps not slower than JavaScript though :)

Comment: @zzxyz CPython is without a doubt significantly slower than v8 JavaScript.

Comment: That’s...impressive.

Comment: You’re probably going to need to narrow this down yourself though. You can make a sample C lib, do timings and then try to get a rough idea of the overhead. If js only supports what's called late-binding (figuring out the call at runtime), you're going to be looking at MS of overhead, and that's unlikely to work.

Comment: How many calls do you need to make per frame from JS to C++? If it's fewer than a few thousand calls, you probably won't have a real performance issue. A V8JS-to-C++ call is a performance hit, but it needn't be a showstopper.

Comment: @Boinst Hmmm, I can't imagine it would ever exceed 200 calls per frame, more like 10 ~ 30 on average, only reaching close to 200 if there's a TON of active objects on screen.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it then @griffort it'll be insignificant

Comment: @Boinst Ahhhh, all right, that makes me feel better about it. I'll try and keep the calls as low as possible, perhaps caching calculated data on the JS side of things when possible. Now that I think about it, only really need to make modifications of JS variables for keeping track of input and stuff, as opposed to making explicit calls back to C++, don't I? Certainly a lot can be handled when on one side of the language or the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is going to be very subjective, it's from observations from my experience that I wouldn't say are very rigorous, I'm working through this issue now myself, and i have not verified my claims with benchmarks. That said...

Yes, calling from JS to C++ is relatively expensive. Certainly more so than calls within pure JS. Substantially more so, in fact, than calls in the other direction, from C++ to JS. I assume that a major cause of the inefficiency is that the javascript engine loses some optimization opportunities.

However, assuming you stick with the V8 engine, calls from JS to C++ will be much faster than calling out into any other language.

Comment: Ahhh, interesting. From your knowledge, at least from a comparative perspective, would there be any other language/framework that would interact better with C++ as a front end (in terms of user-friendly scripting languages)? Or would this probably be the best choice overall?

Comment: @griffort V8 is a solid choice